# Finding anagrams in a list of strings

Tags: java

I have developed the following program to print anagrams using Hashmap in java.But can't figure out what to put inside the line `map.put();` to be used to insert the entry into hashmap.

```
import java.util.*;

class anagram
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String temp;
        int i,n;
        Scanner s1=new Scanner(System.in);
        List<Integer> temp2;
        ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
        HashMap<String,ArrayList<Integer>> map=new HashMap<String,ArrayList<Integer>>();    
        System.out.println("Enter the number of strings");
        n=s1.nextInt();
        //Input the strings and store them in Hashmap after sorting each
        //string on character basis
        //e.g hello , olleh are both stored as "ehllo" --> 0,1
        //"ehllo" is sorted string and 0,1 are its keys
        //In this way, at the end each bucket in hashmap will have anagrams
        //which can be displayed on the basis of keys stored 
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            temp=s1.next();
            list.add(temp);
            //what should I add here to input new string index into proper place
            map.put();
        }

        //Iterating the hashmap to print values of each bucket
        Iterator iterate=map.keySet().iterator();
        while(iterate.hasNext())
        {
            Map.Entry entry=(Map.Entry)iterate.next();
            temp2 =entry.getValue();
            for(i=0;i<temp2.size;i++)
                System.out.print(list.get(temp2.get(i))+" ");
        }   
        list.clear();
    }
    //method to sort the string
    private static String sort(String s)
    {
        char arr[]=s.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        return String.valueOf(arr);
    }
}
```

Comment: `n` is the number of strings the user enters.`i` is used inside for loop

Comment: First, decouple your logic from reading input and see if it gets easier (it will). Also, your code doesn't compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems overhead to store indexes as values.

You could just store input values.
Map would be:

```
Map<String, Collection<String>> anagramsBySortedLettersInThem = ...
```

Then you could use 'classical' pattern:

```
String key = sort(inputString);

if (!anagramsBySortedLettersInThem.containsKey(key)) {
  anagramsBySortedLetterInThem.put(key, new HashSet<String>);
} 

anagramsBySortedLettersInThem.get(key).add(inputString);
```

I use `Set` here, to avoid duplicates. If you need duplicates - use e.g. `ArrayList`

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you have a pretty good plan here. First you need to run  your custom sort function to get the in order string. Then you need to do a get on the hash map to see if you already have a instance of that anagram set.  If the get returns something simply add the index to the associate list.  If not create a new array list,  add your new index and put it using the sorted key.